# Hide Rows on Click Table

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, html-table

I'm trying to create a table that has individual lines with a summary of individual invoices(e.g. Invoice Date, Invoice Total,Status, etc).

I want to be able to click on the row and for it to expand down and show me the detailed information relating to that invoice, however I haven't been able to solve the issue that I need to isolate the row and then expand the new information underneath it?

Keeping in mind a < div > can't surround a < tr > element so I can't hide the < div > and < tbody > wants to encompass the whole table body not just a set of rows.

My PHP and HTML skills I are decent but my knowledge of javascript is not, so any assistance in getting this going is appreciated.

```
 <table>
  <tr><th colspan='6'><h2>Billing Details</h2></tr><tr><td>Invoice ID</td><td>Invoice Date</td><td>Due Date</td><td>Date Paid</td><td>Total</td><td>Status</td>
<?php 
for ($counter = 0; $counter < $invoicesData['numreturned']; $counter++)
{ 
echo "<tr><td>WellConn - " . $invoicesData['invoices']['invoice'][$counter]['id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $invoicesData['invoices']['invoice'][$counter]['date'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $invoicesData['invoices']['invoice'][$counter]['duedate'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $invoicesData['invoices']['invoice'][$counter]['datepaid'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>$" . $invoicesData['invoices']['invoice'][$counter]['total'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $invoicesData['invoices']['invoice'][$counter]['status'] . "</td></tr>";
}
?>  </table>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you post your html? Via `view page source` on your browser so we can have an example to work with?

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern bro..

```
<tr onclick="myFunction()">
<td id="td1" hidden> <?php echo     ?> </td>
</tr>

<script>
function myFunction(){
document.getElementById("td1").style.display = "table-row";
}
</script>
```

Automatically hide the td's.When you click the tr, the td's will show.Cheers bro.

Comment: I had thought about this,The problem with this is that it will only hide a single set of td's, you can't wrap TR's. So i'd need to have all of the invoice information on a single line to get this method to work?